# Drawing Waveforms

Tags: discussion, support

In EE all we need to draw some waveforms to ask or answer questions.

Is this could be done with TeX? Or what are the software's you people are using?

Could we have add some tools to draw waveforms in here?

Comment: We are waiting for circuitlab to have a plugin to integrate with the site fully, but this would only work for circuits, I am not sure what could be done about general waveforms.

Comment: @Kortuk what about LaTeX and the `tikz-timing` package? I posted it as an answer, you might want to have a look at it! ;-)

Comment: [Wavedrom](http://wavedrom.com/) might be a good option. It doesn't have an easy way to do analog waves yet, but it's reasonably powerful and it looks like it'd be simple to integrate into the site. (Might need to restrict scripting for security but the scripting isn't needed for most diagrams anyway.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Software I have on my laptop that can be used for this purpose includes: LTSpice, Scilab, Maxima, Inkscape - which has a nice function generator addin which can be used for quite complex waveforms, you just use a mathematical expression. It's under `Extensions->Render->Function Plotter`

[image: Inkscape Function Plotter]

Math Functions Available:

[image: Inkscape Function Plotter Math Functions]

Comment: what's the name of that extension?

Comment: Oil Glaser, I'll include your last comment to your answer, Because that's what helped me. Then I'll approve your answer. Your last comment most probably have solved my question.

Comment: sorry I couldn't edit it yet. Could anybody please include 2nd comment to the answer. Somebody could edit it?

Comment: @sandundhammika - I added it, with a couple of clips of the dialog box. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

For digital stuff, it's pretty easy to draw waveforms in a general vector drawing package like Inkscape.

The trick is just to set up a reasonable grid and use snap-to-grid to keep your lines lined up.

I would imagine Visio and Dia have similar features.

Answer (score 2):

This indeed is possible with LaTeX using the [`tikz-timing`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikz-timing) package. It isn't included in the markdown editing though. But this might be possible..? It would be really useful, the `tikz-timing` is used by every professional organization to draw logic diagrams in datasheets, application notes, etc...

Answer (score 1):

Some timing diagram answers were listed [in this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/3564/software-to-create-timing-diagrams). [TimingDesigner](http://www.timingdesigner.com/Docs/TD_datasheet.pdf) and [TimeGen](http://www.xfusionsoftware.com/purchase_timegen.html) were mentioned. Another is TimingDiagramer.